# Using numpy to count occurences of list values in a range

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a 2D array of ranges and a list of associated values that I would like to filter. I want to get the number of filtered values that fall into each of the ranges.

For instance, consider:

- the range matrix `{{0,1},{1,4}}`;
- And the list of values `{5,10,16,21}`.

Let's say I filter for `x < 15`. This would give a filtered array of indices `{0,1}`, since only 5 and 10 are less than 15, and they fall at indices 0 and 1 respectively.

Using this filtered array, because 0 falls in the range [0,1) and 1 falls in the range [1,4) this function should return (1,1).

However, if we filter for `x%5 == 1`, the filtered array of indices would be `{2,3}` (because only 16 and 21 mod 5 are equivalent to 1, and 16 and 25 have indices 2 and 3 respectively) and the function should return (0,2) because both 2 and 3 are greater than 1 and less than 4.

I know how to do it with loops, but I'm hoping not too.

I'm not sure what the best way to implement this in NumPy would be -- I'm thinking of using `np.where()` but I'm not sure about the specifics.
Also, not sure if this is the easiest way to go about solving this problem: is there an easier way to determine how many filtered values fall within a range?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). – In particular, it helps to show your current approach (code), and then ***ask a specific question*** based on that approach.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the logic you're looking for. You mention the range (1,3), but there's no such range in your data. In addition, the relationship between the condition (filter), the matrix, and the results are unclear.

Comment: thanks, i fixed the typo and added more explanation. hopefully it makes sense now

Comment: Are the different ranges always adjacent to one another (i.e., the next one starts where the previous one ends)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution (for the case where the ranges / bins are adjacent, which seems to be your case):

```
a = np.array([5,10,16,21])
bins = [[0,1],[1,4]]
bins = [b[0] for b in bins] + [bins[-1][1]]

indices = np.arange(len(a))[a % 5 == 1]
np.histogram(indices, bins)[0]
# array([0, 2])

indices = np.arange(len(a))[a < 15]
np.histogram(indices, bins)[0]
# array([1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for np.histogram()